# Why can't I find resource using pack URI but can with relative path?

Tags: .net, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have a myresource.xaml in my project's Styles folder. I can load it using relative URI(first line), but can't load it with pack URI(second line). Why is it?

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/myresource.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles/myresource.xaml"/>
```

Comment: Is is it in the same assembly?

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian it is in the same application. Otherwise, wouldn't it fail for the first method as well?

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian I've found the problem is that UWP app doesn't recognise pack: URI, not like WPF app. It recognises ms-appx:// URI instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pack URI is a WPF/Silverlight concept. UWP handles loading file resources differently.

To access files from your application package, you can use either a direct or a logical file path to refer to the resource.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/myresource.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Styles/myresource.xaml"/>
```

To access files relative to the current XAML page, you can use a relative URIs.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/myresource.xaml"/>
```

To access files stored in the app data, use the ms-appdata: scheme. App data may be stored in a local folder, a roaming folder, or a temp folder.

To access files stored in the local folder:

```
<Image Source="ms-appdata:///local/images/logo.png" />
```

To access files stored in the roaming folder:

```
<Image Source="ms-appdata:///roaming/images/logo.png" />
```

To access files stored in the temp folder:

```
<Image Source="ms-appdata:///temp/images/logo.png" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I find that accessing resource in DLL (foo.dll) is also "ms-appx:///foo/myresource.xaml"?